# How to remove or modify a review in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I think the title says it all.

Let's say you give a very buggy program an one-star rating, but 6 months later it matured and you want to change your review. Or you just made some typos which need to get fixed. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution i could think of would be to flag the review as inappropriate, and then in the details state that it is inaccurate as it is out of date.  One would hope in the future there will be an interface you can log in with to manage your reviews!

When it asks you to login with a ubuntu software centre account you can login with your single sign in account i believe.

Kind Regards

Comment: You can't report your own reviews in Ubuntu Software. You would have to report the review from another PC.